# Let $H$ be a self-adjoint operator with domain $D(H)$ in a Hilbert space. How to prove $He^{itH}u=e^{itH}Hu$?

Tags: operator-theory

Let $H$ be a self-adjoint operator with domain $D(H)$  in a Hilbert space and the function $e_t:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ continuous and bounded,
 defined by $e_t(x)=e^{itx}$.

I want to know how to prove that we have :

$He^{itH}u=e^{itH}Hu$

for all $u\in D(H)$

Thanks....  (I think we can use spectral theorem but I am not sure)

Comment: by definition, $e^{Y} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{Y^k}{k!}$, and for any constant $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}, k \in \mathbb{N}$ :  $\alpha Y$ commutes with $Y^k$, hence $\alpha  Y$ commutes with $e^{Y}$ : $$\alpha Y e^{Y} = \alpha e^{Y} Y$$

Comment: this is a special case when H is bounded  , here the operator can be unbounded so this doesn t work

Comment: that $Y$ is bounded or not doesn't change that $Y$ commutes with $e^{Y}$

Comment: if it is unbounded the sum has not really a meaning it is not convergent

Comment: I don't understand your point, if $Y$ (and $e^Y$) are unbounded operators, then asking if $Y e^Y u = e^Y Y u$ has a meaning only if $Y u$ and $e^Y u$ exist. and by definition $e^Y$ is the series above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spectral theorem is what you want to use.  Let $X$ denote the Hilbert space on which $H$ operates. In its "multiplier" form, the spectral theorem says that 
there is a $\sigma$-finite measure space $(Y,\mathcal Y,m)$, a unitary operator $U:X\to L^2(m)$, and a measurable function $h:Y\to\Bbb R$ such that $x\in D(H)$ if and only if $h\cdot Ux\in L^2(m)$, and in this case $Hx = U^{-1}M_h(Ux)$, where $M_h:y\mapsto h\cdot y$ is the (densely defined) operator of multiplication by $h$. The associated functional calculus then permits us to define the operator $\varphi(H)$ for suitable $\varphi:\Bbb R\to\Bbb C$. For example, $e^{itH}:=U^{-1}M_{k_t}U$, where $k_t:Y\to \Bbb C$ is the *bounded* function $k_t(y)=\exp(ith(y))$. It's now easy to check that if $x\in D(H)$ then $He^{itH}x$ and $e^{itH}Hx$ are each well-defined, and equal to each other.

Comment: John Dawkins    well done  it s what i was looking for thnak you very much